# Does Sewage Ejector system need a dedicated circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, sump-pump

The sewage ejector system in our basement is on a GFCI outlet that is on the same circuit as the adjacent bathroom (fan, light and switch).

Someone told me it needs a dedicated circuit.  Does the NEC require this? I think it makes sense to share the bathroom circuit. If the pump's breaker trips then how would I know? If the lights are off I'm not going to flush the toilet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on several things.

What size is the circuit?
What else is one it?
What do the manufacturer's instructions say?

Typically you'd only need a dedicated circuit for something like this if it is big enough to warrant it, or if the mfg requires it.

When I say big enough I mean 50% of the circuit size since you are combining a fixed in place appliance (the pump) with general use items.

Answer (score 0):

The pump should not be on the same circuit as the bathroom.

A minimum of 1 dedicated 20A circuit may supply all receptacles to bathrooms BUT ONLY Bathroom receptacles OR a 20A circuit shall be dedicated to all loads to one bathroom and ONLY that bathroom only.

Comment: I'd say that a sewage ejector pump that services a single bathroom and nothing else is a load that's part of that bathroom, no?